# Переменная не взаимодействует с kernel.cl

Tags: c++, cuda, распараллеливание, ядро, opencl

Программа должна вывести максимальное значение массива B. Поиск максимального значения выполняется в ядре.
Столкнулся с проблемой: переменная 'a' никак не меняется после работы программы, хотя в kernel.cl есть обработка: в неё записывается максимальное значение B. В чём проблема? В том, что я неправильно взаимодействую с kernel.cl в main.cpp или в самом kernel.cl мой код работает не корректно?
main.cpp:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <CL/cl_platform.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)
#define LIST_SIZE 25

int main(void) {
    // Создание массива B
    cl_int* B = new cl_int[LIST_SIZE];
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        B[i] = (rand() % 200) / 2.;
    }

    // Загрузка исходного кода ядра
    FILE* fp;
    char* source_str;
    size_t source_size;

    fp = fopen("kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = new char[MAX_SOURCE_SIZE];
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    // Получение информации о платформе и устройствах
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    // Создание контекста
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    // Создание очереди команд
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    // Создание буфера памяти для массива B
    cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(cl_int), NULL, &ret);

    // Копирование массива B в буфер памяти
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(cl_int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Создание буфера памяти для переменной a
    cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(cl_int), NULL, &ret);

    int a;

    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), &a, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Создание программы
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&source_str, (const size_t*)&source_size, &ret);

    // Компиляция программы
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Создание ядра
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "krn", &ret);

    // Установка параметров ядра
    size_t global_item_size = LIST_SIZE;
    size_t local_item_size = LIST_SIZE;  // Локальный размер равен глобальному для данной задачи
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&b_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&a_mem_obj);

    // Выполнение ядра
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Вывод результатов
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nMaximum max(B) = %d\n", a);

    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(a_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    delete[] source_str;
    delete[] B;
    return 0;
}
```

kernel.cl:

```
__kernel void krn(__global const int* B, __local int* local_max, __global int* a, const unsigned int list_size) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int lid = get_local_id(0);

    // Копирование данных из глобальной памяти в локальную
    local_max[lid] = B[i];
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    // Вычисление максимума в локальной памяти
    for (unsigned int stride = get_local_size(0) / 2; stride > 0; stride /= 2) {
        if (lid < stride && i + stride < list_size) {
            int other = B[i + stride];
            local_max[lid] = (local_max[lid] > other) ? local_max[lid] : other;
        }
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    // Первый поток каждой группы записывает максимум в глобальную память
    if (lid == 0) {
        a[0] = local_max[0];
    }
}
```